# Batch append string to column1 of thousands of CSVs (Linux)

Tags: linux, bash, csv, batch-processing

I will illustrate the problem as best I can with an example:

1. I have over 25,000 CSV files in a particular directory.
2. I need to append "-test" to every entry, in the 1st column of every CSV.
3. There are no headers in the CSVs, every entry is unique, every file name is unique.

So this:

```
Column1,Column2,Column3,Column4
Unique,Entry2,Entry3,Entry4
Unique,Entry2,Entry3,Entry4
Unique,Entry2,Entry3,Entry4
```

Would become this:

```
Column1,Column2,Column3,Column4
Unique-test,Entry2,Entry3,Entry4
Unique-test,Entry2,Entry3,Entry4
Unique-test,Entry2,Entry3,Entry4
```

For all the over-25,000-files in my directory.

Is there a bash script that can accomplish this?

***EDIT** CSV's were later found to be comma delimited and surrounded by "s. This change is addressed below.

Comment: This can be done with a [sed](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html) oneliner.

Comment: Hover your mouse over the `batch-file` tag and read the description.

Comment: @Squashman Noted. My bad.

Comment: @IporSircer I was thinking the same, my issue is I'm almost a complete novice and looking for a fast solution, as I'm in a bit of a pickle. Thanks for the input, however.

Comment: parsing CSV and processing strings ? might be more flexible with a Python script (`pandas` or built-in csv module)

Comment: @JosephLathey **With** or **without** one header line?

Answer (score 1):

#### Simply:

```
find . -type f -name '*.csv' -exec sed -e '2,$s/,/-test,/' -i {} +
```

`find` command will generate command lines as long system could hold,

`sed -i` will do *infile changes*, from line 2 to end of file, replace 1st coma `,`, by `-test,`

#### For CSV with ***quotes***:

```
find . -type f -name '*.csv' -exec sed -e '2,$s/",/-test",/' -i {} +
```

#### For CSV with ***quotes***,  ***double-quotes*** or nothing:

```
find . -type f -name '*.csv' -exec sed -e '2,$s/\(["\o47]\?,\)/-test\1/' -i {} +
```

This one will work with CSV like:

```
'Column1','Column2','Column3','Column4'
'Unique','Entry2','Entry3','Entry4'
'Unique','Entry2','Entry3','Entry4'

"Column1","Column2","Column3","Column4"
"Unique","Entry2","Entry3","Entry4"
"Unique","Entry2","Entry3","Entry4"

Column1,Column2,Column3,Column4
Unique,Entry2,Entry3,Entry4
Unique,Entry2,Entry3,Entry4
```

and could render:

```
'Column1','Column2','Column3','Column4'
'Unique-test','Entry2','Entry3','Entry4'
'Unique-test','Entry2','Entry3','Entry4'

"Column1","Column2","Column3","Column4"
"Unique-test","Entry2","Entry3","Entry4"
"Unique-test","Entry2","Entry3","Entry4"

Column1,Column2,Column3,Column4
Unique-test,Entry2,Entry3,Entry4
Unique-test,Entry2,Entry3,Entry4
```

Comment: This is much better than my deleted answer. +1, shame on me that this `sed` didn't occur to me...however, I think OP does not want to skip the 1st line as he says there are no actual headers in the files.

Comment: @PesaThe OP question present samples with header line. For this, I skip 1st line.

Comment: I get why you skip the 1st line, it's in the sample output. Although judging from the positive response from OP to my solution and the sentence `There are no headers in the CSVs` I think it really shouldn't skip them. But that's really up to OP to decide :) you just might mention it if that's the case.

Comment: @PesaThe You're right: I did not read correctly! The question is wrong!

Comment: @PesaThe Your solution worked perfectly for how I outlined the problem (based from how a colleague explained the delimitation), however, now that I have the production files, I realized they were delimited as:

"Unique","Entry2","Entry3","Entry4"

So Output would need to be:

"Unique-test","Entry2","Entry3","Entry4"



I tried using your initial solution, and then using: sed 's/\"//g' file.csv

But no luck :(

Comment: @JosephLathey I have updated my answer. For quoted columns, the fix is simple for both solutions here. it's up to you what you decide to use.

Comment: Thanks @PesaThe for the quick update. For some reason my files are now outputing like so:

"Unique"-test,"Entry2","Entry3","Entry4"
Rather than:
"Unique-test","Entry2","Entry3","Entry4"

Any suggestions? Thanks again!

Comment: @JosephLathey Please edit your question or better: post a new question!

Comment: @JosephLathey I've edited my answer and offer a syntax wich could work with or without, simple ou double quotes.

Comment: @F.Hauri Thanks, that works perfectly for my purposes, you're a livesaver.
Noted, I will edit my original question to reflect the changes. Stack Noob here. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

For variety, let's see a possible solution with `awk`:

```
find /some/path -type f -name '*.csv' -exec awk -i inplace -v FS=, -v OFS=, '$1=$1"-test"' '{}' +
```

**UPDATE:** Simple fix that will work for quoted columns `"Unique","Entry2","Entry3","Entry4"`:

```
find /some/path -type f -name '*.csv' -exec awk -i inplace -v FS='",' -v OFS='",' '$1=$1"-test"' '{}' +
```

Comment: Thank you. This works perfectly for a specific file name, how would I apply this to every file in a directory?

Nevermind, I was being a fool. 

file/*